# multiple processes to update to the correct grid location

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am trying to create three processes that will each eventually pull from a text file and do more complex calculations, but at the moment I am just experimenting with tkinter and multiprocessing. I want each of the three labels(lbl1,lbl2,lbl3) to add 1,2,or 3 to their label and return that value. I am new to pipeing and events and dont understand the way to return the values to the synchronize the values so that they return to the correct places, so the output is random in accordance to the position in the grid. How can I make it so that anything I return only returns to the correct position in the grid which I have already specified?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import  socket, time, datetime, sys, struct
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import shutil
import os
from random import randint
import Tkinter as tk
from multiprocessing import *
#from Tkinter import *

def count1(pipe,stop):
    x = 0
    while not stop.is_set():
        x+=1
        pipe.send(x)
        time.sleep(1)
def count2(pipe,stop):
    y = 0
    while not stop.is_set():
        y+=2
        pipe.send(y)
        time.sleep(1)
def count3(pipe,stop):
    z = 0
    while not stop.is_set():
        z+=3
        pipe.send(z)
        time.sleep(1)

class UpdatingGUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent_pipe, self.child_pipe = Pipe()

        self.stop_event = Event()

        self.num1=tk.Label(self, text="Number 1")
        self.num1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.num2=tk.Label(self, text="Number 2")
        self.num2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.num3=tk.Label(self, text="Number 3")
        self.num3.grid(row=0, column=2)


        # label to show count value
        self.updating_int1 = tk.IntVar()
        self.updating_int1.set(0)
        self.updating_lbl1 = tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.updating_int1)
        self.updating_lbl1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.updating_int2 = tk.IntVar()
        self.updating_int2.set(0)
        self.updating_lbl2 = tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.updating_int2)
        self.updating_lbl2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.updating_int3 = tk.IntVar()
        self.updating_int3.set(0)
        self.updating_lbl3 = tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.updating_int3)
        self.updating_lbl3.grid(row=1, column=2)

        # launch count as a process
        self.counter1 = Process(target=count1,args=(self.child_pipe,self.stop_event))
        self.counter1.start()
        self.update()

        self.counter2 = Process(target=count2,args=(self.child_pipe,self.stop_event))
        self.counter2.start()
        self.update()

        self.counter3 = Process(target=count3,args=(self.child_pipe,self.stop_event))
        self.counter3.start()
        self.update()


    def update(self):
    # While the pipe has data, read and update the StringVar                                                                                
        while self.parent_pipe.poll():
            self.updating_int1.set(self.parent_pipe.recv())
            self.updating_int2.set(self.parent_pipe.recv())
            self.updating_int3.set(self.parent_pipe.recv())

        self.parent.after(1000,self.update)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x200")
    gui = UpdatingGUI(root)
    gui.pack()    
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Each process needs its own pipe to the parent, or you need to send a process identifier/index in the data across the pipe to determine which process the data comes from. As written in the update function, you cannot guarantee the order in which process data is going to be placed in in the pipe.

Try changing the self.parent_pipe, self.child_pipe = Pipe() to three commands:
parent_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
self.parent_pipe.append(parent_pipe)
self.child_pipe.append(child_pipe)

At least that's one way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: ... anything I return only returns to the correct position

Generalize your `def count (...`, to do so add a `position` Parameter.
For instance:

```
def count(position, pipe, stop):
    x = 0
    while not stop.is_set():
        x += 1
        pipe.send((position, x))
        time.sleep(1)

def update(self):
    # While the pipe has data, read and update the StringVar                                                                                
    while self.parent_pipe.poll():
        position, data = self.parent_pipe.recv()
        if position == 1:
            self.updating_int1.set(data)
        elif position == 2:
            # and so on
```

Comment: I dont think pipes can return two values that way

Comment: Try it or leave it.

Comment: didnt solve the problem but got me thinking in the right way, thanks